# What is the meaning of $H in Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, mootools, jsfiddle

[This jsfiddle.net example](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/) includes `$H`:

```
new Request.JSON({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        json: JSON.encode({
            text: 'some text',
            array: [1, 2, 'three'],
            object: {
                par1: 'another text',
                par2: [3, 2, 'one'],
                par3: {}
            }
        }),
        delay: 3
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + v
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

I can't seem to find the meaning/function of $H.  Can someone elaborate?

Comment: In the fiddle Mootools is selected.

Comment: Retagged.  (stupid 15 char limit)

Comment: $H is also a thing in the Prototype JavaScript framework, from which Mootools was developed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$H is to do with mootools, not jQuery. You find the doc [here](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/8436053/MooTools) (pg 67). Excerpt below:

> $H  is a shortcut to initialize an
>   instance of  Hash .  Usage :
>   $H(object)  Example :
>       var fooHash = $H({foo: 'bar'});   When you’ll use it : This is just a
>   shortcut for  new Hash(obj) , which
>   returns an instance of  Hash

Answer (score 2):

`$H` is just a function, defined by one of the other scripts in (or linked in from) the page.  JS identifiers can contain $; it's just used because it looks special (and mortals are so used to the "only word chars" rules for identifiers, that it's unlikely to conflict with other people's stuff).

Look through the other scripts for a function named $H, or for some code that copies/moves $ (a very common name in frameworks, and thus, likely to conflict) to something else.